# How do I load part of a view immediately and delay other parts in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple view that looks like this:

```
%h1 Charts

= high_chart "chart1", @chart1
```

The `h1` and the rest of the framework takes 200ms to load and is quite static. However, the chart takes over 10 seconds to load due to heavy calculations done by the controller. As a result, the entire webpage takes 10 seconds to load because it's waiting for the chart calculations to be completed.

How can I load the rest of the webpage, minus the chart, and wait for the chart to load while the user sees the rest of the webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solutions would be to extract high_chart part into a separate view and load it with ajax.
So your view would look like:

```
%h1 Charts
#highCharts
```

And then assuming you make '/high_charts' to return high_charts part, you can make an ajax request to /high_charts, right after the page is loaded and prepend it to #highCharts div, when the response is got:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/high_charts',
    success: function(response) {
      $('#highCharts').prepend(response);
      // Initialize high_charts if needed
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This might need some callbacks for the Highcharts Javascript library to render the data once AJAX has completed.

Comment: This is working pretty well, however all I get back currently is the header and footer from that page whereas I want just the chart. Is there a way to get just the chart? Do I have to change the `/high_charts` view?

Comment: Never mind, found a solution. However, the chart itself isn't loading. Moved to a [different question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735639/why-doesnt-highcharts-render-when-i-pull-it-in-with-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Jquery lazy loading`. In your view, write code for `h1` and all other parts except `chart`. In your Chart controller, create a method to render a particular partial where chart is supposed to be rendered.

```
class ChartsController
  def show_chart
    render 'chart_file',layout: false
  end
end
```

Add a Jquery script as below,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  $.ajax({
    url: '/chart_controller/show_chart',
    data: {},
    success:function(data){
      $("#chart_div").append(data);
    }
  });
}
```

So at-first, this will load rails View with minimal content, then it'll fetch chart with Ajax so it'll be non-intrusive.

Make necessary changes in controller and view code to work.

Resources,

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

https://api.jquery.com/ready/