# Why doesn't HighCharts render when I pull it in with Ajax?

Tags: ajax, highcharts

I have a chart that loads just fine at the path `/charts/chart1`. To separate the long load times of the chart with the rest of the webpage, I'm using Ajax to load in the chart. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/charts/chart1',
    success: function(response) {
      $('#firstChart').append(response);
    }
  });
});
```

However, the chart is not loaded in to the `#firstChart` `<div>`. The id of the actual `div` at `/charts/chart1` is `#chart1`.

I've tried reloading the chart by adding the following code:

```
chart1 = $('#chart1');
options = chart1.highcharts().options;
chart1 = new Highcharts.chart(options);
```

When running this code in the console on `/charts/chart1`, I reload the exact same chart. However, when running this on on the page that made the Ajax call, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: chart1.highcharts is not a function`. Also, `Highcharts.charts` in the console returns an empty array, meaning the chart is not being pulled with the Ajax request.

Why does the chart load fine when going to `/charts/chart1`, but the chart doesn't load when loading via Ajax?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can create a jsFiddle, use the echo @ http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html for emulating ajax

Comment: How your "response" looks like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Highcharts library is being loaded on the page making the AJAX request. You don't need to load Highcharts on `/charts/chart1` unless you are looking to also make that page available to stand alone. The important thing `/charts/chart1` needs to supply is the data inside `$('#chart1').highcharts({ ... });` that will tell the Highcharts library how to render your chart on the page making the AJAX request.

In fact, loading the Highcharts library on both `/charts/chart1` and on the page making the AJAX request will probably give you [Highcharts Error #16](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16) because Highcharts is being loaded multiple times.

Otherwise your AJAX function is correct, and I was able to make it work for me on localhost with an example Highchart. If you still have issues, double check that your `/charts/chart1` path really does return the Highcharts data to the requesting page.